# Center of the group $\langle x,y\mid (xy)^l=(yx)^l\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

In my study of Artin groups I need to compute the center of the group $G=\langle x,y\mid (xy)^l=(yx)^l\rangle$.

Of course, if $r= (xy)^l=(yx)^l$ then  $yr=y(xy)^l=(yx)^ly=ry$ and $xr=x(yx)^l=(xy)^lx=rx$ and so $r\in Z(G)$ so it is obvious that $\langle r\rangle\subset Z(G)$ and from these one can deduce that $\langle xy\rangle\subset Z(G)$. However, I am not sure wheter this is an equality or I am missing something in the center.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If $xy\in Z(G)$ then $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, no?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven this group is known to be non-abelian, so unless I made a mistake the quotient is not cyclic.

Comment: So since the group $\langle x,y\mid xy\rangle$ is clearly $\mathbb Z$...

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I see, I am checking what I've done and maybe I made a mistake and $xy\notin Z(G)$. Then $Z(G)=\langle r\rangle$?.

Comment: I would guess so, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$G/\langle r \rangle = \langle x,y \mid (xy)^l \rangle \cong \langle x,y \mid x^l \rangle,$$
which is the free product of an infinite cyclic group and a cyclic group of order $l$, and has trivial centre by the general theory of free products.

So $Z(G) = \langle r \rangle$.

Comment: Are you sure this is right? You are saying that $G/\langle r\rangle$ contains a subgroup of order $r$, but $r$ is not an integer, it is an element of $G$.

Comment: Sorry, I do this kind of thing more and more often. Maybe I am going dyslexic. I hope it is right now!

Comment: right, thanks for your help!!!!